# Python multiprocessing process number

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using Python multiprocessing pool module to create a pool of process and assign jobs to it.

I have created 4 process and assigning 2 jobs but trying to display their process number but in the display I just see one process number "6952"...Shouldn't it print 2 process number

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep

def f(x):
    import os 
    print "process id = " , os.getpid()
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes

    result  =  pool.map_async(f, (11,))   #Start job 1 
    result1 =  pool.map_async(f, (10,))   #Start job 2
    print "result = ", result.get(timeout=1)  
    print "result1 = ", result1.get(timeout=1)
```

Result :--

```
result = process id =  6952
process id =  6952
 [121]
result1 =  [100]
```

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just down to timing. Windows needs to spawn 4 processes in the `Pool`, which then need to start up, initialize, and prepare to consume from the `Queue`. On Windows, this requires each child process to re-import the `__main__` module, and for the `Queue` instances used internally by the `Pool` to be unpickled in each child. This is takes a non-trivial amount of time. Long enough, in fact, that when you both of your `map_async()` calls are executed before all the processes in the `Pool` are even up and running. You can see this if you add some tracing the the function run by each worker in the `Pool`:

```
while maxtasks is None or (maxtasks and completed < maxtasks):
    try:
        print("getting {}".format(current_process()))
        task = get()  # This is getting the task from the parent process
        print("got {}".format(current_process()))
```

Output:

```
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
got <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
process id =  5145
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
got <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
process id =  5145
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
result =  [121]
result1 =  [100]
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
got <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
```

As you can see, `Worker-1` starts up and consumes both tasks before workers 2-4 ever try to consume from the `Queue`. If you add a `sleep` call after you instantiate the `Pool` in the main process, but before calling `map_async`, you'll see different processes handle each request:

```
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
# <sleeping here>
got <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
process id =  5183
got <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
process id =  5184
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
getting <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
result =  [121]
result1 =  [100]
got <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
got <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
got <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
got <ForkServerProcess(ForkServerPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
```

(Note that the extra `"getting`/`"got"` statements you see are sentinels being sent to each process to gracefully shut them down).

Using Python 3.x on Linux, I'm able to reproduce this behavior using the `'spawn'` and `'forkserver'` contexts, but not `'fork'`. Presumably because forking the child processes is much faster than spawning them and doing a re-import of `__main__`.

Answer (score 0):

It does print 2 process ids.

```
result = process id =  6952  <=== process id = 6952
process id =  6952  <=== process id = 6952
 [121]
result1 =  [100]
```

This is because your worker process finished quickly and was ready to process another request.

```
result  =  pool.map_async(f, (11,))   #Start job 1 
result1 =  pool.map_async(f, (10,))   #Start job 2
```

In the code above, your worker completed the work and returned back to the pool and was ready to complete job 2. This can happen for multiple reasons. The most frequent ones are that the worker is busy, or is not ready.

Here is an example where we are going to have 4 workers, but only one of them is going to be ready right away. Thus we know which one is going to do the work.

```
# https://gist.github.com/dnozay/b2462798ca89fbbf0bf4

from multiprocessing import Pool,Queue
from time import sleep

def f(x):
    import os 
    print "process id = " , os.getpid()
    return x*x

# Queue that will hold amount of time to sleep
# for each worker in the initialization
sleeptimes = Queue()
for times in [2,3,0,2]:
    sleeptimes.put(times)

# each worker will do the following init.
# before they are handed any task.
# in our case the 3rd worker won't sleep
# and get all the work.
def slowstart(q):
    import os
    num = q.get()
    print "slowstart: process id = {0} (sleep({1}))".format(os.getpid(),num)
    sleep(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4,initializer=slowstart,initargs=(sleeptimes,))    # start 4 worker processes
    result  =  pool.map_async(f, (11,))   #Start job 1 
    result1 =  pool.map_async(f, (10,))   #Start job 2
    print "result = ", result.get(timeout=3)
    print "result1 = ", result1.get(timeout=3)
```

example:

```
$ python main.py 
slowstart: process id = 97687 (sleep(2))
slowstart: process id = 97688 (sleep(3))
slowstart: process id = 97689 (sleep(0))
slowstart: process id = 97690 (sleep(2))
process id =  97689
process id =  97689
result =  [121]
result1 =  [100]
```